# Bing Maps REST - Javascript

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am a beginner with JavaScript and I am facing some issues with parsing JSON and display the data I want to.
When I run the URL manualy in browser I get a correct result back.

The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
request = "URL"
function CallRestService(request, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: request,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function (r) {
            callback(r);
            var results = data.resourceSets;
            console.log(r.message);
            alert(r.statusText);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Error" + JSON.stringify(e));
            console.log("Error" + e.message);

        }
    });
}
```

When I run this code I get no error in the console but I still get an alert via the error function: "status":200,"statusText":"OK"
Why do I get this?

And thats why I cannot get my data displayed, what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

so I was able to make a working code out of it, but I still get messages from SUCCESS and ERROR at the same time and I also get my data back?!

```
<script>
var request = "URL";

function CallRestService(request, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: request,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        success: function (r) {
            callback(r);
            console.log("working" + r.message);
            alert(r.statusText);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Error" + e.message + JSON.stringify(e));
            console.log("message: " + e.message);
            console.log("readyState: " + e.readyState);
            console.log("responseText: "+ e.responseText);
            console.log("status: " + e.status);



        }
    });
}
CallRestService(request, GeocodeCallback);
function GeocodeCallback(results) {
console.log(results.resourceSets[0].resources[0].travelDurationTraffic);
document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML=Math.round((parseFloat(results.resourceSets[0].resources[0].travelDurationTraffic) / 60));
}


</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that alert from the error function? You are creating an alert in the success function too.

Comment: yes I removed the success line just to be sure, its 100% from the error function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you put an actually URL into the request parameter this looks fine. A 200 status means it was successful and this likely called the console from your success function. I know you said you removed it to be sure, but the page could of been cached. If you take a look at the network request you will likely see that it was successful as well. Ifs possible that an error in your success function is occurring and triggering the error function. Have you tried adding break points inside of the two functions?

Here is a blog post that shows how to access the Bing Maps REST services using jQuery and other frameworks: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/03/05/accessing-the-bing-maps-rest-services-from-various-javascript-frameworks/ It looks like your code is very similar.

Comment: hi thanks for your respond, yes there is an working URL. 
at the moment I receive messages from both, success and error, which is really strange, but I also get the result back which I want.

The error message is : 
message: undefined
test.php:25 readyState: 4
status: 200

and form the success I get:

unfefined

Comment: about the link to the blog, yes I am using this code as a template

Comment: ReadyState 4 is good, it means the request finished and the response is ready. 200 means the request was successful. Looking at your success function you have a line "var result = data.resourceSet", but data is undefined, which is likely were your error is.